# EF 4 Code First: with existing tables

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have an existing table in my database and I want to create some additional tables using Code First/Fluent API (whatever way you may want to categorize it). Following is my `DbContext`:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Entity1> Entities1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Entity2> Entties2 { get; set; }

    public MyContext() : base(@"data source=....;")
    {}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MyContextInitializer());
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Entity1Configuration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Entity2Configuration());
    }
}
```

After going through some questions here and some blog-posts I found following way suggested to create non-existing tables:

```
public class MyContextInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(_mainTable);
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(_relationTable);
        base.Seed(context);
    }
    private readonly string _mainTable=@"create table ...";
    private readonly string _relationTable=@"create table ...";
}
```

But the `Seed` method in `MyContextIntializer` is not called may be database already exists. If I move `ExecuteSqlCommand` statements to `OnModelCreating` statement in `MyContext` I get following error:

```
The context cannot be used while the model is being created.
```

What are my other options than running SQL directly in SQL Management Studio to create tables?

Comment: Don't you wanna to create these tables just once? Because it makes sense, create a separate method and call it only once, when needed. Not when the model is being created (aka everytime you run the application).

Answer (score 1):

#### Description

I have done the same a few months ago.

You can map your Model to an existing Database.
Scott Guthrie has blogged about it.

I encourage you to use the **Enity Framework Power Tools** to create your models and context from your existing Database.

#### More Information

- [Using EF “Code First” with an Existing Database](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx)
- [Entity Framework Power Tools CTP1](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d)

### Update

You must set the initializer for the DbContext, if you don't do that your new Initializer will not used. Do the following on Application start.

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new MyContextInitializer());
```

Comment: As you can see I'm using `Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new MyContextInitializer());` in `OnModelCreating`. I have moved this line into `ApplicationStart` also but still the method (`Seed`) to call custom sql code is not being called.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot Do you want to create the database delete and create the database every time (for development) or do you want to execute the sql every time ?

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot That's because `MyContextInitializer` is based on `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`, hence it'll be called only when the database doesn't exists, `Seed` method included.

Comment: @cincura.net right. i just want to know what the goal is, to update my answer.

Comment: @dknaack I have one table and I was trying to find out if EF 4.1 Code First can somehow create new table and required many-to-many relationship table. I have already ran the sql code manually to create remaining tables but was looking for some automated way like `SubSonic 3` etc. without drop-recreate cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled migrations? If not, that is the likely reason. Fo you have a Migrations folder, does that folder have a Configuration file? What does the constructor look like? Here what it should look like:

```
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }
```