# Connect to several SQL Servers

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, database-connection

I have several databases located in many SQL Servers (2008) in Local Network. All of these databases have the same structure and tables, the only difference among them is the data.
I need a software that when users input the address of a specific server with username and password, the software just has the right to log in to that server and retrieve data from that server.

If I use Connection String like this:

```
string server_address = "...";
string database = "...";
string username = "...";
string password = "...";        
string connectString = "Data Source=" + server_address + ";Initial Catalog= " + database + ";uid= " + username + ";pwd= " + password + "\"";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectString);
conn.Open();
....
conn.Close();
```

I can manage my problem with this type of connection.

However, I use LINQ to retrieve data and the connection string is stored in file "app.config". So, how can I change this string in this file?
For example, my current test connection string app.config is:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyProgram.Properties.Settings.TestDatabaseConnectionString"
connectionString="Data Source=172.16.1.73;Initial Catalog=TestDatabase;uid=sa;pwd=1"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I run this in my computer just for testing, but when this program is run on another computer, users must input the server address "172.16.1.xxx", username and password. How can I make the program change these in app.config file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you describe the symptom rather than your contrived answer? I would bet this could be solved more effectively another way if we understood the problem domain better.

Comment: There is a post in stackoverflow related to this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759631/using-entity-framework-with-multiple-ms-sqlserver-databases

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do something like this:

// Northwnd inherits from System.Data.Linq.DataContext.

```
Northwnd nw = new Northwnd(@"northwnd.mdf");
```

// or, if you are not using SQL Server Express

```
Northwnd nw = new Northwnd("Database=Northwind;Server=server_name;Integrated Security=SSPI");
```

(example from MSDN).